# How to conditionally format strings in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, text, printf, text-formatting

This is something that I have been trying to figure out for a while but cannot quite figure it out.

Let's say I have these four elements:

- `name = "Mark"`
- `location = ""`
- `time = Time.now`
- `text - "foo"`

And if I used `str#%` for formatting, like so: `"%s was at the location \"%s\" around %s and said %s" % [name,location,time.to_s,text]`, how would I avoid the problem of blank spaces and orphaned words? (For example, "Mark was at the location "" around 2011-12-28T020500Z-0400 and said foo")

Are there any other techniques that I could use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just build the string piecemeal and assemble the results. You could easily cleanup the following if you had access to .blank? (I think it's blank?)

```
parts = []
parts << name if name && !name.empty?
parts << "was" if name && !name.empty? && location && !location.empty?
parts << %{at location "#{location}"} if location && !location.empty?
parts << "around #{time}"
parts << "and" if location && !location.empty? && text && !text.emtpy?
parts << "said #{text}" if text && !text.empty?
parts.join(" ")
```

Comment: Yes, it would be blank. I do have Active Support installed so I can just put in `require 'active_support/core_ext/object/blank'`.

Comment: And that is what I've been thinking, too.

Doing something like `parts << "and" if !location.blank?` would work well.